# The number of roots for polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots

Can a $5$-th grade polynomial have only one solution? for example: 
$$x^5 - 3x^4 + 17x^3 - 12x^2 - 11x - 5 = 0$$

I mean that it's not necessary for every seventh grade polynomial to have seven solutions. There may be only one or three. The same for a sixth grade polynomial, there may be only two solutions.

If this is true, then how I can decide if a fifth grade polynomial has only one solution or three and not five solutions?

Comment: Well, you could have $x^5$, that only has $0$ as a root.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yup, this is another example of what I meant.

Comment: The only root I found for the polynomial in my question is 1.47494..

Comment: The accepted terminology is *degree* and not grade.

Comment: @AhmedAmir Look at the answer and think if you could find more roots in a different field than $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: That is the only real root, though there are four complex roots.  There isn't a general method for finding roots, sadly.  It may help to remark that a multiple root is also a root of the derivative, and it's a lot easier to find common roots of two polynomials of close degree.

Comment: Are you familiar with derivatives?  If so, I can write out an approach for detecting multiple roots.

Comment: I'm not familiar with derivatives.. But I couldn't find the other four complex roots.. Is that mean that "1.47494" is the only multiple root for this polynomial? @lulu

Comment: @AhmedAmir No. Look at the answers. The fact that you couldn't find them does not mean that they don't exist. There are four (not real) roots left.

Comment: @Edu Then what are the other four not real roots for that polynomial? I used a program to get all roots (real and not real) and this was the only answer..

Comment: Here is a picture which shows the location of all of the complex roots of your polynomial: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EUZ8.png The roots are (approximately) {-0.320745 - 0.331599i, -0.320745 + 0.331599i, 1.08328 - 3.84111i, 
 1.08328 + 3.84111i, 1.47494}

Comment: @AhmedAmir You can find the roots of a polynomial (or at least an approximation, like in this case) in the Wolfran Alpha webpage: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5+-+3x%5E4+%2B+17x%5E3+-+12x%5E2+-+11x+-+5+%3D+0 As you see, there are one **real** and four complex roots. A total of $5$ (complex) roots, as the theorem in the answers states.

Comment: Well, how could I find these roots without using the "Wolfram Alpha" or any other software for such a polynomial? I did solve many other examples with (no real roots) but I couldn't solve this one manually..

Comment: @AhmedAmir, you may be interested to know that there is likely no way to solve this "by hand" (meaning without a computer). Beyond 4th degree polynomials there is no general formula to write down their roots. This is known as the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).

Comment: I see.. Thanks for your clarifications and for such a useful tool "Wolfram Alpha"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fundamental Theorem of Algebra**

Every non-zero, single-variable, degree $n$ polynomial with complex coefficients has, counted with multiplicity, exactly $n$ complex roots.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The comments clarify that the OP is curious about unique zeroes.

Comment: You might have made less mystifying for the OP if you had said "exactly $n$ _complex_ roots".

Comment: @Sloan My answer was posted before the comments and I explained that you need to look at multiplicity. If there are further questions motivated by the answer, anyone can ask in the comments...

Answer (score 5):

A 5th degree polynomial (with real coefficients) has at least 1 real root.
A polynomial of odd degree has at least 1 real root.

The fundamental theorem of algebra says that a polynomial roots equal to its degree.  However, they may be complex and they may be roots of multiplicity.

$x^2-1$ has 2 real roots.
$x^2+1$ has 2 complex roots.
$x^2-2x + 1$ has one root of multiplicity 2.

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a simple algorithm for generating a lot of polynomials with degree $5$ and a single real root:

1. Take a second-degree polynomial $p(x)$
2. Consider the fourth-degree polynomial $q(x)=p(x)^2$
3. Take some $C\in\mathbb{R},D\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and define $Q(x)$ as $C+D\int_{0}^{x}q(t)\,dt.$

$Q(x)$ is a fifth-degree polynomial with a single real root, since it is a continuous, weakly increasing and unbounded (in both directions) function over $\mathbb{R}$. For instance, with the choices $p(x)=x^2+3$, $C=0,D=5$ we get
$$ Q(x) = x^5+10x^3+45x $$
whose only real root lies at $x=0$.

The main algorithm for counting the number of real zeroes of a polynomial is given by [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem), but yet the computation of the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) gives you some information.

Comment: Well, this is interesting.. I will definitely look at this again after getting into calculus.

Comment: May I ask the reason behind the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The polynomial

```
(x - r)^5
```

has one root r with multiplicity 5.

In general one can [construct a polynomial ( function ) with desired properities](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/construct)